# How to merge many API call into one in swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
func getCar(session: String, CarHandler: @escaping (Result<CarResponseModel, Error>) -> Void) {
    let url = MAIN_URL + "/user/car"
    
    AF.request(url, method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Accept":"application/json", "session":session])
                .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
                .responseDecodable(of: CarResponseModel.self) { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let response):
                    CarHandler(.success(response))
                case let .failure(error):
                    CarHandler(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
}

func getHouse(session: String, HouseHandler: @escaping (Result<HouseResponseModel, Error>) -> Void) {
    let url = MAIN_URL + "/user/house"
    
    let parameters = ["name": "houseName"]
    
    AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: ["Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Accept":"application/json", "session":session])
                .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
                .responseDecodable(of: HouseResponseModel.self) { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let response):
                    HouseHandler(.success(response))
                case let .failure(error):
                    HouseHandler(.failure(error))
                }
            }
}
```

Question

Use two functions to get car and house information. I wonder if it's possible to put this together.

Reason

The idea that if I receive information using only one communication function, I can handle the error at once.

My idea

The parameters or get, post information for handing over to the server are made by another function using communication and handed over to one communication function

Desired result

```
func getData(request, AllHandler: @escaping (Result<AnyModelStruct, Error>) -> Void) {
    AF.request(request)
                .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
                .responseDecodable(of: AnyModelStruct.self) { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let response):
                    AllHandler(.success(response))
                case let .failure(error):
                    AllHandler(.failure(error))
                }
            }
}
```

Problem

```
func getData(request, AllHandler: @escaping (Result<HouseResponseModel, Error>) -> Void) {
    AF.request(request)
                .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
                .responseDecodable(of: HouseResponseModel.self) { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let response):
                    AllHandler(.success(response))
                case let .failure(error):
                    AllHandler(.failure(error))
                }
            }
}
```

...

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

I know that url, method, parameters, encoding, header information can be generated and handed over as a request,

I don't know how to give and receive a model...

Model information is required for escape and response decoding. Is there a way to hand over the model information here? Or is it possible to set the Any type?

Others

Lastly, I would like to know a tip on how to proceed when I perform many API requests in other projects, if the method I'm trying now is not a popular method.

Comment: You need [generic function](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)

Comment: As previously suggested, you can use Generic. In fact, you were already using it, but not seeing it: the `.responseDecodable(of:)` is a generic here. Create your own generic method. "Mimic" that logic on your implementation.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. First, you can create a base service to generate AF requests**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class BaseService {
    
    public static let shared = BaseService()
   
    private var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: Constant.API_BASE_URL)!)
    
    private init() {}
    
    public func generateRequest(url: String, method: HTTPMethod, body: Data?) -> URLRequest {
        
        guard let formateUrl = URL(string: url) else {
            fatalError("Invalid URL")
        }
        
        request.url      = formateUrl
        request.method   = method
        
        if let body_data = body {
            request.httpBody = body_data
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }
        
            
        return request
    }
}
```

**2. You need to create a generic method for calling API requests**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
    
    struct API {
        
         private static let decoder = JSONDecoder()

         static func getRequest<T: Decodable>(urlPath: String, model: T.Type, completed: @escaping(Result<T, AFError>)-> Void) {
    
            let request = BaseService.shared.generateRequest(url: urlPath, method: .get, body: nil)
    
            AF.request(request).validate().responseDecodable(of: model.self, decoder: decoder) { (response) in
                
                switch response.result {
                    
                case .success(let result):
                    
                    completed(.success(result))
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    
                    completed(.failure(error))
                
                }
            }
    }
```

**3. After that, You can call the previous method anywhere with any JSON model**

```
API.getRequest(urlPath: "YOUR API PATH", model: HouseResponseModel.self) { result in
            
            switch result {
                
            case .success(let res):
                print(res)
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think I've seen issues with a "static“ decoder and threadinig. I'd use instead a "new one" each time, so in this case a computed property.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for your comment. Are there any issues?

Comment: I think I got some EXC_BAD_ACCESS, that's why, but to confirm.

Comment: @Larme You are correct, I changed the answer. I think now okay.